# Is approved iOS in-app purchase available in back app versions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My current iOS app version has a couple of in-app purchases. I am now submitting a new iOS version for approval. I am also, along with that, submitting a new in-app purchase for approval.

If the new version and in-app purchase get approved, will the new in-app purchase also be available in the previous app version? (I don't want to force users to upgrade immediately in order to purchase the new thing.)

Comment: Would your old version have the details of the product code to request and the code to provide whatever is purchased?

Comment: Yes, that comes from my server, not hard-coded into the app.

Comment: Try to update in-app purchase before starting updating new version. So you can check you can use these in older version. Then you can update your app.